# Using react component in a different application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

What I'm trying to achieve is:

1. Building simple `react app` - the template is `create react app`
2. Copying output file (main.*.js)
3. Pasting it in another `react app`
4. `Importing` render function to render the first app into the second one

Simple react app code:

```
interface Props {
  greeting: string;
}
export module AppModule {
  export const sendGreetings = ({ greeting }: Props) => {
    return `Hello ${greeting}`;
  };
}
```

Builder file code:

```
!function(){"use strict";var n;(n||(n={})).sendGreetings=function(n){var e=n.greeting;return"Hello ".concat(e)}}();
```

Trying to import this file into another app I get this error:

```
File 'c:/vscode/test-react-app/test-sc-react/src/main.783e0281.js' is not a module.ts(2306)
```

Which is obvious. I  changed the output file manually to:

```
export function initApp(){"use strict";var n;(n||(n={})).sendGreetings=function(n){var e=n.greeting;return"Hello ".concat(e)}};
```

It works but the only function that I'm able to access is `initApp` but not `sendGreetings`

I've been struggling with this for a while now and I would really appreciate any helpful suggestions

Comment: I think your best bet is to communicate through global window object. in your sub application export any functions or values to window[myvalue] so the global apps, or side apps can access that.

Comment: It is a bit different, but maybe module federation could suit you:
https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/

Comment: Do you want to import your react app at runtime or build time?

Comment: You should look into the concept of micro-frontend which enable you to share code between projects even regardless of the source technology (for example you can even construct your application with different frameworks like React and Angular)

Answer (score 1):

Solution #1

You can use an iframe to inject your react app:

```html
<iframe src='path-to-your-app.html'/>
```

Solution #2

Go with [micro-frontend](https://micro-frontends.org/) architecture approach. Where a front-end app is decomposed into individual, semi-independent "microapps" working loosely together.

As a starting point, you can try `npx create-mf-app` instead of the CRA.

Answer (score 0):

I used [Bit.dev](https://bit.dev/) for my components that are used across multiple applications & there is an article regarding your issue

https://blog.bitsrc.io/sharing-react-components-across-multiple-applications-a407b5a15186

I think it would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can include your js code directly on run time. You can use `window.addEventListener` to `load` js/css incoming from an outside source. You just have to append that js to your `document` on the `load` event.